# Get keys from Mongo db using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a db schema:

```
'use-strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var groupUsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groupNames: {}
});


mongoose.model('grouproles', groupUsersSchema);
```

In this I am storing a Json. From the schema I need to get the keys in that JSON . The JSON is:

```
{'Mathematicians': ['euclid', 'riemann', 'euler', 'gauss', 'test'], 'Scientists'
: ['einstein', 'galieleo', 'tesla', 'newton']}
```

I am storing the JSON as :

```
var groupData = new Groups({
       groupNames : {data}
     });
```

where **Groups** is the model name

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to get the Keys from the db . ie I need to retreive (Mathematicians,Scieneits) . To be more clear , need to retreive attribute names from db

Comment: use the find operation and loop in array select, use `Object.keys` to get keys from the objects

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that finds the document that you need and then use Object.keys on the found document to retrieve the keys of the document.

Answer (score 0):

make use of `Object.keys`

```js
var a = {'Mathematicians': ['euclid', 'riemann', 'euler', 'gauss', 'test'], 'Scientists'
: ['einstein', 'galieleo', 'tesla', 'newton']}

console.log(Object.keys(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Object.keys(obj) is one way which already other people have suggested.

2) You can also use [Schema Path](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-eachPath) to achieve this but that will give you all the attributes of the object, including the methods.

3) If you require keys very often then you can also store them as a separate document and fetch it very easily at any time.

```
var groupUsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groupNames: {your_json_data}
    groupFieldName : [your_keys]
});
```